# Using a parameter as a filter - Multiple values not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The report works for just 1 choice, but when I add more than one, it does not return anything ( no errors, just nothing in the report).

My SQL statement includes the parameter `@Region`

`where Region_Name IN (@Region)`

In the Region parameter's properties, I set to allow multiple values.

in the dataset filter's properties:

**Expression:** `=Fields!Region.Value`
**Operator:** `IN`
**Value:** `=Parameters!Region.Value(0)`

*EDIT
I removed the dataset filter as suggested.

Below are the properties for the parameter.
The available values come from another data set that is a distinct list of regions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you referencing the `Region` parameter in both the `Expression` and `Value`?

Comment: @iamdave, not really sure to be honest. I was following the thread and adapting.

Comment: I updated my question to using a @Region Parameter in the SQL statement

Comment: Using `=Parameters!Region.Value(0)` specifies the first parameter value with the `(0)`. Try just using `=Parameters!Region.Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a parameter to go back and forth between the stored procedure and the report, I created the parameter and used it in the tablix properties.

Expression:  =Fields!Region.Value
Operator: IN
Value: =Parameters!Region.Value

When you first create the value, it adds a (0) to the end of the expression. Remove that and it works as expected.

Thank you @iamdave for the help!

EDIT:

I came back to this and was able to filter using the parameter and stored procedure.

I followed a link from a question to here: http://www.codeulike.com/2012/03/ssrs-multi-value-parameters-with-less.html

I created a dataset parameter and removed the one from the tablix properties. Then created the function provided and it worked. I did not mess with the "ALL" features in the post.

Thanks for all the tips. Brent

Comment: So you are aware, this *isn't* filtering your query.  The query returns your entire dataset and the the report uses only the data that matches the filter.  It is *much* more efficient to filter the SQL as in my answer than just the dataset.  Also, specifying that your dataset is calling a stored procedure is important information that was left out of your question.

Comment: Dave (@iamdave),

Yes, I am aware I am pulling in the entire data set, but it's a small table with just a few thousand rows. Ideally, I would set it up using the parameter, but after I figured out I would need to parse the data, I choose to take a quicker route to complete the task. I am still interested in figuring out how to do it the correct way. 

Yes, I did leave that out and I apologize. I have only been working with SSRS a short time, so quite a bit of this is new to me and it's something I just missed. 

Thanks for the feedback and help. Brent

Answer (score 0):

Your edit makes a lot more sense.  To use multivalue parameters you just need to reference the parameter in the usual way, except use `in` within the SQL:

```
select cols
from table
where specificcol in @Region
```

And then don't have a dataset filter set, just make sure there is a reference to the `Region` parameter in the `Parameters` property page.  The filtering of the data is handled by the inclusion of the parameter in the SQL, so you don't need to *also* have a filter on the SSRS dataset.

Comment: Hello,

Yes, I am referencing to the parameter in my SQL code 

WHERE Region_Name IN (@Region)

I removed the filter from the data set as you suggested.

I am not certain about this:  make sure there is a reference to the Region parameter in the Parameters property page

I will update my post with pictures of the parameter's properties>

Comment: @Brent  The image you have added is for the Parameter Properties, whereas I am referring to the Parameter page within the Dataset Properties window.  Apologies, I could have explained that a bit better.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, the parameter is showing in the dataset properties. I am calling a store procedure and found an article I might need to address the parameter a bit differently. I tried this =JOIN (Parameters!Region.Value,",") in the parameter value expression window, but the same result of the report working with 1 selection chosen but does not work with more than 1 selection

Comment: Using the JOIN in the parameter value did not work, but I think my issues come from the fact I am using a stored procedure and passing my @Region parameter values.

Comment: I think I will switch gears on this. Instead of using the stored proc, I will bring in all the values and then try using the tablix property to filter my regions. using the stored proc is making it tougher than it needs to be. I have that much working so far with the rub that the "All" only displays the first choice.

Comment: You can probably just copy the contents of the stored proc's code into your dataset query. Post you stored proc so we can see what it does. You should try to filter the data as early as possible to save bringing back lots of data tha you don't need.

Comment: @AlanSchofield,  I tried to copy the stored proc into the dataset query, but it did not work. Not sure I can post the entire stored proc, but the field I am using the query on is pretty simple. The value is a region as in North, South, East and West. In the final select statement of the procedure, I have set the region to equal my parameter. 
where Region_Name IN (@Region)